# обновление sphinxsearch

Tags: linux, search, sphinx, sphinxsearch, ppa

после обновления sphinx 2.0.4 из 2.2.10 не запустился search

```
>search test
Программа 'search' на данный момент не установлена. Вы можете установить её, выполнив:
sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

и не могу подключится

```
>mysql -P9306 --protocol=TCP
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)
```

**уточнения**
 - search на 2.0.4 работал)
 - mysql -P9306 --protocol=TCP на 2.0.4 проходил
 - sphinx 2.0.4 ставил с репа (apt-get install sphinxsearch)
 - sphinx 2.2.10 устанавливал отсюда 
http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/ по средством скачивания и запуска deb пакета
 - об обновлении задумался так как новый проект на установленном sphinxsearch запускаться не соизволил, на сервере установлен 2.2.9

**логи** /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log

```
 [Tue Dec  1 15:07:06.766 2015] [31657] watchdog: main process 31658
   forked ok<br/>
[Tue Dec  1 15:07:06.768 2015] [31658] listening on all interfaces, port=9312<br/>
[Tue Dec  1 15:07:06.768 2015] [31658] listening on 127.0.0.1:9306<br/>
[Tue Dec  1 15:07:06.770 2015] [31658] FATAL: binlog meta file <br/>/var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/binlog.meta is v.4, binary is v.5; recovery requires previous binary version<br/>
[Tue Dec  1 15:07:06.772 2015] [31657] watchdog: main process 31658 exited cleanly (exit code 1), shutting down<br/>
```

**вопрос**
как заставить заработать обновленный sphinxsearch или как переустановить его с минимальными движениями напильника. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

systemctl status sphinxsearch.service что выдает?
стартаните демон если он выключен, search больше нету - используйте mysql клиент

Comment: >systemctl status sphinxsearch.service<br/>
systemctl: команда не найдена<br/>

>sudo searchd
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
precaching index 'filter'
precaching index 'search_ru'                     
precached 2 indexes in 0.001 sec                            

без изминений

Comment: >sudo service searchd start
//
searchd: unrecognized service

Comment: searchd вроде как запускается, но он не является сервисом

Answer (score 1):

потратив времени разобрался.
searchd при запуске как сервис валился изза отличия версий binlog.meta 
после того как я задал в конфиге sphinxsearch путь к логам все завелось

searchd{
...
binlog_path = /path/to/writable/dir
...
}